# Multiple keys with WPF KeyDown event

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard, keyboard-events, keydown

I'm working with WPF KeyDown event (KeyEventArgs from Windows.Input). I need to recognize when user pressed F1 alone and Ctrl+F1.

```
   private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key==Key.F1 && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ctrlF1");
        }
        if (e.Key == Key.F1 && !Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("F1");
        }
    }
```

My problem is that when I press Ctrl+F1  plain F1 messagebox would fire too. I tried to add e.Handled to Ctrl+F1 case, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
else if.....
```

In your case both options are fired, because you press the F1 key in both cases.

Answer (score 5):

Use if and else otherwise all conditions get evaluated.

```
   private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Key==Key.F1 && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl))
       {
           MessageBox.Show("ctrlF1");
       }
       else if (e.Key == Key.F1 && !Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl))
       {
           MessageBox.Show("F1");
       }
   }
```

Comment: works. but still can't understand why it fires in my case. When I press F1 Ctrl is pressed, so !Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) should be false

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [Keyboard.Modifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.modifiers(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) > 0)
{
    button1.Background = Brushes.Red;
}
else
{
    button1.Background = Brushes.Blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check Key.F1 first, and if it pressed, then Key.LeftCtrl:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.F1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) ? "Ctrl-F1" : "F1");
    }
}
```

Comment: But how you to pass bothe keys together?? When i wanted to hit alt+f1 while debugging i found that the debugger hits on alt itself and never gets evaluate to true for next condition after &&.