# Detect multiple pure alphabets key in WPF

Tags: wpf, events, keyboard-events

If I want to detect multiple alphabet keys ( like `DI` for example) in my WPF app. How can I do it? Note that I only care to fire my events when I have detected multiple alphabet keys ( no `CTRL`, no `SHIFT`, no `1`, `2` or `3`..., just `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and so on).

I tried something like

```
 if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.D) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.I))
```

But it didn't work at all.

[The solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30941971/multiple-keys-with-wpf-keydown-event) I find mostly has to do with one of the keys is a [modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.modifierkeys?view=net-5.0). So it doesn't really fit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Once I encountered a very same situation in which I could not detect several keys when pressed at the same time. The thing I was missing (which you may also be) was that I did not declare the code in the window's function itself. After writing that code inside the main window's `KeyDown()` function, it worked. After declaring the function for the window, you may try the code below to see if it actually works on your side.

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.A) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.B) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.S))
     {
          // Whatever you would like to do
          MessageBox.Show("Pressed!");
     }
}
```